# How to import fonts to Notepad++?

Tags: web, notepad++

I use Notepad++ to write websites and I'm using the "consolas" font, but I would like to use "inconsolata" which is not available in the Style Configurator (version 6.9.2). Is there a way to import a font to Notepad++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use all installed fonts. So download the consolas [OpenType](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/Inconsolata.otf) file, run it and click `Install`.

From there you should be able to select it in Notepad++

Make sure to check "Enable global font" (also font size, and the various global font styles).

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that one must check "Enable global font" in order for this to take effect. At least, that was my experience.